# Why can't I change the dtype of a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, integer, data-science, imputation

I am doing some Kaggle competition called **TitanicSpaceship** (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/spaceship-titanic) and I had an error:

```
train['CryoSleep'] = train['CryoSleep'].map({'False':0, 'True':1}).astype(int)
IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

I don't know what to do.

I tried to see if there was a problem with Pandas function called dropna() but it did not change a thing.

Comment: Why dont you try running a unique command on your given series, and check all the given values?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does not support NAN values in INT series.
You can either:
a) drop rows that contain NAN values and convert to INT
b) convert to FLOAT, if that is appropriate for your case